Stackblitz "Failed to run start command"
Today I wanted to continue working on my Github reposiroty via Stackblitz and ran into some issues. For some reason I'm not able to start the terminal process to start the live server. I need it to see how my changes with eleventy are working.
This is what my command prompt is showing at the start:
~/phillippdi/JAMStack-PaperJourney
❯ npm install && npm start

up to date in 3s

44 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

> jamstack-paperjourney@1.0.0 start
> eleventy --serve

jsh: permission denied: eleventy

~/phillippdi/JAMStack-PaperJourney main 4s
❯ loadenv /home/phillippdi/JAMStack-PaperJourney/.env /tmp/previous-env
loadenv: loading /home/phillippdi/JAMStack-PaperJourney/.env

~/phillippdi/JAMStack-PaperJourney main
❯ 

On the other side Stackblitz is telling me that it failed to run the start command in this process.
All it tells me is Please restart your terminal processes.
On the right side of the img you can see the note:

I already tried to restart the process and also to rerun the eleventy process with npx @11ty/eleventy, npm install and npm start (start is my --serve alias).
Also, I enabled WebAssembly on my browser by adding [*.]staticblitz.com as an exception.
I never ran into troubles like this before and hope that somebody can help me to solve this issue.
Thanks beforehand!

EDIT
I was able to solve the problem. jsh was denying permission to start the process. All I had to to was type in npm rebuild and everything is fixed.
